# How to change LaTeX package default download website?

Tags: installing

I'm trying to install "mh" package, using MiKTeX Package Manager, however, it failed, the log says:

```
Installation directory: C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX
package repository:
http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 2e1ee451b3ebfd4ef4afc81bbceafc9f
going to download 2154149 bytes
going to install 20 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading
http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mh.tar.lzma...
```

Then I check the website http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ , actually there is no such "mh.tar.lzma" file, instead, there is a "mathtools.tar.lzma", which actually I can download.

What can I do to install the mh package?

Comment: mh seems to obsolete and replaced with mathtools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last summer the `mh` package was split into `mathtools` and `breqn`, with distinct maintainers and consequently, MiKTeX's corresponding package was split. 
You should synchronise the package repository (`Repository menu->Sonchronize`in MiKTeX Package Manager).